# Clarification of Nokogiri::NodeSet XML Content based on 'puts node' and 'puts node.inspect'

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

I rarely use xpath() but when I do I keep tripping myself up on interpreting content of Nokogiri::Nodesets and believe I now know where I have always gone wrong.

Simply put when I do a 'puts NodeSet' I have always assumed that I could search the Nodeset based on the returned XML.  But the first tag returned does not appear to actually part of the node XML.

'puts n1' returns XML that has a SPAN as the first element of the XML, but if I then do an search n1.xpath('SPAN') or n1.xpath('SPAN/DIV') no nodes are found.  n1.xpath('DIV') returns the output I expect and proves no SPAN tag in the XML.

The only way I can logically explain this to myself is if assume that the first xml tag of a 'puts node' is the "Node Name" and not part of the node XML. This works for me going forward but am I missing something that is going to bite me elsewhere.

CODE:

```
docxml = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)  
<DIV><SPAN><DIV id='1'><H1>-H1-</H1><h1>-h1-</h1></DIV>
<DIV id='2'><H2>-H2-</H2> <h2>-h2-</h2></DIV>
<DIV id='3'><H3>-H3-</H3><h3>-h3-</h3></DIV>
</SPAN></DIV>
EOT
n0 = docxml.xpath('DIV')
n1 = n0.xpath('SPAN')
n2 = n1.xpath('DIV') 
n3 = n2.xpath('*')
n4 = n3.xpath('*')  

puts "n1:xpath('SPAN'): \n#{n1.xpath('SPAN')}\n#{'^'*80}  \nn1 XML:\n#{n1}\n#{'^'*80}\
\nn1:inspect  \n#{n1.inspect}\n#{'^'*80}\n"
OUTPUT:
=begin
n1:xpath('SPAN'): 
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  
n1 XML:
<SPAN>
  <DIV id="1">    <H1>-H1-</H1>    <h1>-h1-</h1> </DIV>
  <DIV id="2">    <H2>-H2-</H2>    <h2>-h2-</h2> </DIV>
  <DIV id="3">    <H3>-H3-</H3>    <h3>-h3-</h3> </DIV>
</SPAN>
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   
n1:inspect  
[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x1c10964 name="SPAN" 
    children=[
        #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x1c10820 name="DIV" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x18fff90 name="id" value="1">] 
            children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x1c1064c name="H1" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x1c1ffe8 "-H1-">]>, 
                      #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x1c10604 name="h1" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x1c1fdcc "-h1-">]>
            ]>, 
        #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x1c107d8 name="DIV" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x1c1fc10 name="id" value="2">] 
            children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x1c105bc name="H2" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x1c1f874 "-H2-">]>, 
                      #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x1c1f778 " ">, 
                      #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x1c10574 name="h2" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x1c1f5f8 "-h2-">]
            >]>, 
        #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x1c10790 name="DIV" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x1c1f43c name="id" value="3">] 
            children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x1c1052c name="H3" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x1c1f0a0 "-H3-">]>, 
            #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x1c104e4 name="h3" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x1c1ee90 "-h3-">]
        >]            
  >]
>]
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
=end
```

Comment: I am 77 retired and only program (for my own pleasure) in winter (Nov thru March here) so have to relearn a lot of things every year.  Do not do well with documentations so code to understand  and then created code snippets that I can refer to in the future.  This is part of my basic xpath code snippet and want to ensure I understand NodeSet content or that my interpretation is accurate enough to always be used without problem.

Answer (score 0):

Now that I have had some sleep this works for me.

'nodeset = xpath(tag1/tag2)' returns a 'nodeset' containing member node 'tag2'

'puts nodeset'              displays the 'tag2' node member

'nodeset.xpath('*')'        returns the content of 'tag2

'nodeset.xpath('tag2')'     invalid as 'tag2' is not part of the content of 'tag2'